# How can I prevent iOS 15.1 Safari from cutting of the content of the webpage during reload?

Tags: html, mobile-safari, ios15

I have discovered that iOS 15.1 iPhone 7 Safari cuts of webpage content during reloads(not related to the flexible viewport height). If the user would have a bad connection or the server is slow, the slow reload could lead the user to start scrolling down/up the current page, and see a broken design/cut off page.

Has anyone else seen this bug on another device? *Does anyone know of a trick to prevent the cutoff?*

**How to reproduce:**
I am using a node dev server and a simple html file(no styling) to see the bug. First start the server, then load the page on your phone. If you then cut the server and try to reload on the phone, you should see the bug. Make sure the html file is long enough!

Comment: Hi @johann1301s I am facing the same problem, did you find any solution to the issue?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution yet...